# easy way to randomize the entries of an array using stl?

Tags: c++, stl, arrays, random

I can sort a int* array using stl,
plain and simple like

```
std::sort(myarray, myarray + size);
```

Is there any equal simple way to randomize it?

thanks

Comment: @Partial: It also needs more brackets. :-P

Comment: Just sort it and call that randomized! It's one possible result from "randomizing" it, after all.

Comment: @Chris Jester-Young: And it obviously needs parameters and a semicolon at the end! What I wrote was only a correction to what was written in the question.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

[`std::random_shuffle`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/random_shuffle)`(myarray, myarray + size);`

Comment: +1, also, Boost.Random has some good random number generators to go with it, if you want something higher-quality than the RNG used by default. :-P

Comment: Who says it doesn't use a high-quality RNG already? :P At least with your own RNG you can control it, which is immensely useful for things like unit tests.

Answer (score 7):

If you want to generate new random content instead of shuffling the elements that are already there:

```
std::generate_n(myarray, size, &std::rand);
```

Comment: +1: I don't think this is what the questioner meant, but well done for noticing the ambiguity in "randomize" :-)