# Generating unique random numbers in a multi dimensional array in C++

Tags: c++, c

I am trying to create a 3x5 two dimensional array that contains the values 1-15 in a randomized order so that each number will only be used once.

Comment: Do you have any specific question about this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [easy way to randomize the entries of an array using stl?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2208411/easy-way-to-randomize-the-entries-of-an-array-using-stl)

Answer (score 4):

Generate a vector or array containing the numbers 1-15 and then use [`std::random_shuffle`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/random_shuffle), putting the result in your array.

Comment: This is actually a much easier solution +1

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using [boost random](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/doc/html/boost_random.html) and using the [uniform int](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/doc/html/boost_random/reference.html#boost_random.reference.distributions) or uniform small int distribution